# Adding JPanel constructor to JPanel shows up gray

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Very new to Java (and programming in general)
I am trying to set up this layout and am trying to construct a JPanel based on a switch from:

```
public class PrimaryDisplay extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int option = 0;

public int getOption() {
    return option;
}

public void setOption(int option) {
    this.option = option;
}

public PrimaryDisplay(int primaryChoice)  {
    setOption(primaryChoice);

    switch (getOption()) {
        case 1: //fixate
            //JPanel primaryScreen = new JPanel();
            //primaryScreen.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            //primaryScreen.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
            JLabel fixate = new JLabel();
            fixate.setText("+");
            fixate.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 1, 50));
            fixate.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            fixate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            fixate.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            //.add(fixate);
            break;

        case 2: //

    }
}
}
```

and calling that constructor from a main:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main {
public static JFrame fullFrame = new JFrame();
public static JPanel primaryContainer = new JPanel();
public static JPanel hmdContainer = new JPanel();
static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
static int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
static int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
public static int primaryChoice = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fullFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    fullFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fullFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    fullFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    primaryContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    primaryContainer.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    hmdContainer.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    hmdContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    JPanel filler = new JPanel();
    filler.setBackground(Color.RED);
    primaryContainer.add(filler);

    PrimaryDisplay prim = new PrimaryDisplay(primaryChoice);        
    primaryContainer.add(prim);

    HMD hmdDisplay = new HMD();
    hmdDisplay.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    hmdContainer.add(hmdDisplay);

    GridBagConstraints m = new GridBagConstraints();
    m.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    m.gridwidth = 1;
    m.gridheight = 1;
    m.weightx = .7;
    m.weighty = 1;
    m.gridx = 0;
    m.gridy = 0;
    fullFrame.add(primaryContainer, m);
    m.gridy = 0;
    m.gridx = 1;
    m.weightx = .3;
    fullFrame.add(hmdContainer, m);     
    fullFrame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

and it only ever shows up as a grey box....?
probably very simple solution but I am stumped at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: Start by making sure that you start you application within the context of the EDT, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Is this: `//.add(fixate);` deliberate?

Comment: *"and it only ever shows up as a grey box....?"* - When I run your code, I get a red and green box and a gray box where the `+` is displayed (if I uncomment `//.add(fixate);`), do you mean the `+` panel is grey?

Comment: yes, I want the + panel to show up, but it is gray.it does not appear to make a difference whether those lines are commented out or not. (btw it should say primaryScreen.add(fixate); )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "believe" this is what you are trying to achieve...

[image: Boxes]

The main reason the "+" panel is gray is because, by default `JPanel` is opaque, therefore it covers whatever is behind it...

If you change the `opaque` property to `false` in the `PrimaryDisplay`, it will become transparent allow the parent container to show through...

```
public PrimaryDisplay(int primaryChoice) {
    setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: ah ha.  Make sense.when I add that line, i see the yellow background without the +

Comment: Well I was just guessing at what you wanted added to it ;)

Comment: ok. so when i extend jpanel i can just add directly to it with add.xxx rather than having to add an additional jpanel,, not sure what i was thinking there.  thanks as always

Comment: Yep, `JPanel` is just another `Container` ;)